# C# disable windows scrollbar but enable custom scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, scrollbar, panel

I have a panel, a custom scroll bar and a problem.

First : I need to use this custom scroll bar because it's for tablet PC and I need to add some features to this scroll bar.

But my problem : The custom scroll bar is working, but I need to disable the windows scroll bar because I have 2 horizontal and 2 vertical scroll bar (mine + windows).

Already tried **AutoScroll** = false, but disable all scroll bar. And **panel.HorizontalScroll.Visible** = false doesn't work, all scroll bar stay visible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not using the windows scroll bar and making your custom features within it, I don't remember it has anything to do except showing without defining custom actions

Comment: Windows scroll bar don't allow you to change the width for the VerticalScrollBar for example. And my Tablet PC are on the factory, user can't use stylus. With finger, scroll bar is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen an example that may answer your question.
the idea is: to put all your controls in a panel define the scrollbar control outside it and make your panel respond to your added scroll bar.
I think this will work, idea and way is shown on this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C#

Comment: can we also use this for flow layout panel?